# UIViewController: adjust contraints of xib

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

In my project I defined a xib and a ViewController that will contain the xib.

```
class FeedDetailViewController: UIViewController, FeedDetailDelegate {

  var feedDetail: FeedDetail!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    feedDetail = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FeedDetail", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)! as! FeedDetail
    feedDetail.delegate = self;
    self.view.addSubview(feedDetail)
    self.adjustContraints()
  }

 func adjustContraints() { 

    feedDetail.sizeThatFits(self.view.frame.size)

    var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: feedDetail,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: feedDetail,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: feedDetail,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: feedDetail,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(constraint)

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

What I want is simply the xib at "fullscreen", but xib borders are not "sticked" to the main view of the controller.

[image]

Border legend:

- red: self.view
- yellow: feedDetail
- others: element inside feedDetail (test only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call this method before adding constraints.

```
feedDetail.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```